# Call nodejs script from php script

Tags: php, node.js, http

Imagine I have a feature coded on nodejs because it implements a library which solves pretty well my problem and I want to add this feature on another PHP script that makes more stuff.

Is a good practice just call the nodejs script with `shell_exec`? Or should I code a standard communication protocol between them like HTTP requests? Am I coding too much instead of just run `shell_exec`?

Comment: yo can use REST API using curl

Comment: yes, I know, but it isn't too much code for just call an script? Do you think is a really bad practice call it using shell_exec? And with curl you could have communication problems and more delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice to call the script directly from the PHP code or via a http request is completely at your own discretion. However, you should measure the cost effect performance-wise.

If calling the script directly will not compromise the performance of the PHP code, then it is perfectly fine. You should also consider the long run effect of this. If the data you're processing will grow over time, then depending on you algorithm, and the Big-O effect of the data size, then this won't be an effective method.

The all round best approach will be to go the path of the micro-services concept. You could create an external API that will execute the script externally (with your data), and import the result back into the PHP process. The only drawback from this is the cost, especially if this will require you to acquire other CPU resource(s).